# JavaScript: How to keep data returned by a set of REST calls for later use

Tags: javascript

Given the following object:

```
var MyObject = function(field1, field2) {
  this.field1 = field1;
  this.field2 = field2;
}

MyObject.prototype.setField1 = functioin(field1) {
  this.field1 = field1;
}

MyObject.prototype.apply = function() {
  ...
  this.setField1("hello");
  log("field1: " + this.field1); // field1 has not been set to "hello"
}
```

I want to change the value of `field1`... but the code above doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? Tx.

**EDIT**

OK, it's worth providing you with the real case. Here below is my customization of Swagger for dealing with JWT:

```
var TokenAuthorization = function(appId, value) {
  this.appId = appId;
  this.value = value;
  this.type = null;
  this.expirationTime = null;
};

TokenAuthorization.prototype.set = function(value, type, expirationTime) {
  this.value = value;
  this.type = type;
  this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
};

TokenAuthorization.prototype.apply = function(obj, authorizations) {
  var now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  var appId = this.appId;
  var value = this.value;
  var type = this.type;
  var expirationTime = this.expirationTime;

  if (value == null || (type == "browse" && this.expirationTime <= now)) {
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:9000/auth";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: baseUrl + "/apps/" + appId + "/apikey"
    }).done(function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ principal: appId, secret: data.apiKey }),
        url: baseUrl + "/apps/credentials",
        contentType: "application/json"  
      }).done(function(data) {
        value = data.token;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          headers: { "Authorization": "Token " + value },
          url: baseUrl + "/users/credentials"
        }).done(function(data) {
          type = data.token.header.typ.split('/')[1],
          expirationTime = data.token.claims.exp
        })
      })
    });
  }

  this.set(value, type, expirationTime);

  log("token: " + this.value); // value is null
  log("typ: " + this.type); // type is null
  log("exp: " + this.expirationTime); // expirationTime is null

  obj.headers["Authorization"] = "Token " + this.value;
  return true;
};
```

The code above performs three REST calls to obtain a token and let the client application browse thru the API. Finally, here is how I create the object:

```
window.authorizations.add("authToken", new TokenAuthorization("myApp", null));
```

Since I pass `null` as the second parameter (token), I need to get a `browse` token for the current client app. That's it.

I guess the problem has to do with the fact I'm performing async REST calls.

Comment: How do you use your class? Cus I don't see anything worng here.

Comment: Assuming you copied and pasted the code given here: you misspelled function, thereby resulting in failed compilation.

Comment: It's awfully helpful to describe exactly what "doesn't seem to work" means.

Comment: where are you doing `new` of the function, & using?

Comment: You have a typo in your code : functioin => function. It could not working because of that error.

Comment: The code does work if you fix the typo and `log` is defined. This question should be closed.

Comment: This question can be answered now, can be reopened. It was more of asynchronus flow problem than property setting on object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some debugging I figured out what problem was. ajax is async, so `apply` returns immediately and of course the data is still `null`.

Rewriting the code like this solved the problem:

```
var e = (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : exports);

var TokenAuthorization = function(appId, token, type, expirationTime) {
  this.appId = appId;
  this.token = token;
  this.type = type;
  this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
  this.locked = false
};

TokenAuthorization.prototype.lock = function() {
  this.locked = true;
};

TokenAuthorization.prototype.unlock = function() {
  this.locked = false;
};

TokenAuthorization.prototype.apply = function(obj, authorizations) {
  var now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  if (!this.locked && (this.token == null || (this.type == "browse" && this.expirationTime <= now))) {
    var baseUrl = obj.url.split("api-docs")[0] + "auth";
    var appId = this.appId;
    this.lock();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: baseUrl + "/apps/" + appId + "/apikey"
    }).done(function(result) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ principal: appId, secret: result.apiKey }),
        url: baseUrl + "/apps/credentials",
        contentType: "application/json"  
      }).done(function(result) {
        var token = result.token;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          headers: { "Authorization": "Token " + token },
          url: baseUrl + "/users/credentials"
        }).done(function(result) {
          e.authorizations.add("authToken", new TokenAuthorization(
            appId, token,
            result.token.header.typ.split('/')[1],
            result.token.claims.exp
          ));
          log("token: " + token);
          obj.headers["Authorization"] = "Token " + token;
        })
      })
    });
  } else if (!this.locked) {
    obj.headers["Authorization"] = "Token " + this.token;
  }
  return true;
};
```

This way, if a token already exists, it is used as is, otherwise a new one will be set once the REST calls complete.